# Difference between initial scale and user scalable

Tags: html

What is the difference between `initial-scale` and `user-scalable` ? Because I feel there is no difference between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`initial-scale` and `user-scalable` serve different purposes, and they are far from being the same:

- [`initial-scale`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-device-adapt/#initial-scale0):

  - Specifies the initial zoom factor for the window or viewing area.
  - It translates into `zoom` property.
  - Internally, its values are translated into numeric values in the range [0.1, 10].
- [`user-scalable`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-device-adapt/#the-user-scalable-property):

  - Specifies if the user will be able to change the zoom factor.
  - It translates into `user-zoom`.
  - Internally, its values are translated into `zoom` or `fixed`.

So you will use `initial-scale` to specify how zoomed/scaled the page will be when it loads, and you will use `user-scalable` to specify if the user will be able to zoom in/out interacting with the page.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Now I have clear idea about it.